# Check user language selection in NSIS MUI2

Tags: internationalization, installation, translation, nsis

I have multiple language packs in my NSIS installer, using the MUI2 interface. Now I try to select the language pack, which is installed by the "Typical" installation type according to the user's chosen setup language. My problem is, that I can't figure out, how to get the user's language selection.

I already tried to access the variables $LANGUAGE and $mui.LangDLL.RegistryLanguage, as well as trying to compare a defined language string to a specific translation string, but without success.

Comment: Maybe you can post some example code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The language can only be set in `.onInit` (By using the LangDll plugin or setting $LANGUAGE directly) After .onInit, language strings are loaded but you can still check $LANGUAGE to get the language id...

Comment: All I am trying to do is accessing the selected language. Comparing $LANGUAGE works for me. In my previous try I must have misspelled it.